# NetLogo: setup world size by slider in code not in "Settings"?

Tags: debugging, netlogo

I would like to implement as a **slider** my **world size** (centered, square) in NetLogo GUI - in code, not through "settings" options. 
However I don't know how and where to write it in my code? I know that I can use world-width and world-height as reporters in BehaviorSpace, but I want to change world's parameters interactively.

I thought I could simply write it in to `setup` procedure:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set world-width world_size
  set world-height world-size
  setup-turtles
  setup-patches
end
```

or to write it in

```
to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    set world-width world_size
    set world-width world_size
  ]
end
```

in both approached I have en error: `This isn't something you can use "set" on.`

I'm sure that it is trivial question, but I can't find my answer.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at the `resize-world` primitive in the dictionary

Comment: hi JenB, thank you, I put resize-world 15 -15 15 -15  into my setup procedure an dgot an error: You must include the point (0, 0) in the world.
error while observer running RESIZE-WORLD
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'. How can I include point 0,0 to my world ? If i am using "re-size" I thought my origin will be the same?

Comment: you mean `resize-world -15 15 -15 15`. min, max, min, max.

Comment: oh these signs... Thank you I didn't notice that !

Answer (score 3):

Final code - use slider to determine world size, thanks to @JenB and @SethTisue:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ; use slider "world-size" in GUI
  resize-world (world_size * -1)  world_size (world_size * -1) world_size 
  ; resize-world -15 15 -15 15 ;   example without slider
  setup-patches
end
```